# Meaning of cmap in contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, 2d, colorbar, contourf

I have two questions regarding usage of the `contourf` plotting function. I have been searching for answers but haven't found them.

1. In the `contourf` function, there is a variable named `cmap`. What is this used for and what is its meaning? And what is `cmap=cm.jet` mean?
2. When one puts x,y,z into `contourf` and then creates a colorbar, how do we get the minimum and maximum values by which to set the colorbar limits? I am doing it manually now, but is there no way to get the min and max directly from a `contourf` handle?

Comment: `cmap` is a color map, try `cm.gray` for comparison. The colorbar should use the min/max of your plot. If I'm misunderstanding your question, why not post an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `cmap` kwarg is the [colormap](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) that should be used to display the contour plot. If you do not specify one, the jet colormap (`cm.jet`) is used. You can change this to any other colormap that you want though (i.e. `cm.gray`). `matplotlib` has a large number of [colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) to choose from.

Here is a quick demo showing two contour plots with different colormaps selected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10,10)

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
con = plt.contourf(data, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.title('Jet')
plt.colorbar()

hax = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
con = plt.contourf(data, cmap=cm.gray)
plt.title('Gray')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

As far as getting the upper/lower bounds on the colorbar programmatically, you can do this by getting the `clim` value of the `contourf` plot object.

```
con = plt.contourf(data);
limits = con.get_clim()

   (0.00, 1.05)
```

This returns a tuple containing the (lower, upper) bounds of the `colorbar`.

Comment: Thank you for your lucid answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: But is there also any easy way to figure out the min and max of the z data being put into contourf? Instead of first plotting it corasely to get the max and min, it would be helpful if there were a automatic way from which i can then construct levs=np.linspace(min,ma,10000) to pu into the contourf levels argument.

Comment: @user4437416 If you want to do that I would just use the range of the data itself to determine `min` and `ma`. `min = data.flatten().min()` and `data.flatten().max()`